# Android: can not use JSON parse in fragment with asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem when trying to parse JSON data from localhost to fragment android using AsyncTask.

**this my code FindPeopleFragment.java**

```
    public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String nim;
    JSONArray str_json = null;
    String surl = "http://10.0.2.2/siakad/jadwal.php?nim=125410295&&jam=10:00 - 12:30";
    TextView isinya;

    public FindPeopleFragment(Bundle b){
        nim = b.getString("par_kode");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        if (container == null)
        {
            return null;
        }


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
        isinya=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.isi);

        new AmbilData().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        String matkul;
        String ruang;
        String dosen;
        String sks;
        String jamkul;
        String kelas;
        String hari;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Sabar gan, masih ngambil data neh...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


        }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... result) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(surl);
            return json;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                str_json = result.getJSONArray("jadwal");

                for(int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);

                    matkul= ar.getString("matkul");
                    sks = ar.getString("sks");
                    hari = ar.getString("hari");
                    jamkul = ar.getString("jam");
                    ruang = ar.getString("ruang");
                    kelas = ar.getString("kelas");
                    dosen = ar.getString("dosen");

                    isinya.setText("Matakuliah : "+matkul+
                            "\nSks : "+sks+
                            "\nHari : "+hari+
                            "\nJam : "+jamkul+
                            "\nRuang : "+ruang+
                            "\nKelas : "+kelas+
                            "\nDosen : "+dosen);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("hasil", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**and in my JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject AmbilJson(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
      // defaultHttpClient
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "n");
      }
      is.close();
      json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
      jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

**And I have some errors in my LogCat :**

```
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 58: http://10.0.2.2/siakad/jadwal.php?nim=125410295&&jam=10:00 - 12:30
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at sob.akademik.JSONParser.AmbilJson(JSONParser.java:35)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at sob.akademik.FindPeopleFragment$AmbilData.doInBackground(FindPeopleFragment.java:164)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at sob.akademik.FindPeopleFragment$AmbilData.doInBackground(FindPeopleFragment.java:1)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-31 04:25:46.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2985):     ... 4 more
```

please help me to fix this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the stack trace, all will be revealed. The URL you are providing is not valid.

Consider using `android.net.Uri.Builder` to construct valid URIs.

For example:

```
new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority("10.0.2.2")
    .appendPath("siakad")
    .appendPath("jadwal.php")
    .appendQueryParameter("nim", "125410295")
    .appendQueryParameter("jam", "10:00 - 12:30")
    .build();
```